# Draw a polygon when space bar is pressed - Pygame (Python 3.6)

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I have a problem with pygame: I'd like that when I press the spacebar appears a square but I'm surely making a mistake because it doesn't become visible every time I press the key and it appears for a frame. My idea is that the square goes up and then falls down when reachs the top of the screen. Can I do this with a while loop? Every correction is helpfull because I rarely code and I have only read a guide about pygame.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
bianco=(255,255,255)
nero=(0,0,0)
rosso=(255,0,0)
verde=(0,255,0)
blu=(0,0,255)
display=pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Prova")
px = 400
py = 360
h=40
lead_x_change = 0
lead_y_change = 0
axx = px
axy = py-30
uscita = False
while not uscita:
    display.fill((86,170,239))
    main = pygame.draw.rect(display,rosso,[px,py,30,h])    
    pygame.draw.rect(display, verde,[0,400,800,800])
    px += lead_x_change
    py += lead_y_change
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            uscita = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                lead_x_change +=1
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                lead_x_change +=-1
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                pygame.draw.rect(display,rosso,[100,100,100,100])

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                lead_x_change = 0
            #if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            #    pygame.draw.rect(display, blu,[0,400,800,800])
    pygame.display.update()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    clock.tick(175)
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

-------------- EDIT ----------------

```
# - updates -

player_rect.x += lead_x_change
player_rect.y += lead_y_change

if display_rect:
    red_rect.y -= 5
    if red_rect.y == 0:
        go_down = True
if go_down:
    red_rect.y += 5
```

To get the red_square down I tried this, but I have probably misunderstood the advice... 
I wrote in the object part `go_down = False` while in the updates part I added the code up here. The result is the same of the previous attempt without `go_down` variable

Comment: Do you want to create only one square or multiple? And should the square only be there if the space-bar is held?

Comment: For the movement and bouncing, read [this tutorial](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_animation&lang=en#section_8).

Comment: when you press space then set `display_rect = True` and use it after `for event` loop to `draw.rect()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before main loop create variable

```
display_rect = False
```

and when you press space change value

```
if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
    display_rect = True
```

and later use this value to draw rectangle

```
if display_rect:
    pygame.draw.rect(display, RED, [100, 100, 100, 100])
```

If you want to toggle (show/hide) using space then use

```
if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
    display_rect = not display_rect
```

If you want add more rectangles when you press space then create list

```
tracks = []
```

and add new rect to this list

```
if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
    tracks.append(player_rect.copy())
```

and later use this list to display rectangles

```
for item in tracks:
    pygame.draw.rect(display, BLUE, item)
```

BTW: I use [pygame.Rect()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) to keep player size and position (and to draw rect) so later I could use it to check collisions ie.

```
player_rect.colliderect(enemy_rect)

player_rect.collidepoint(mouse_position)
```

Code:

```
import pygame

# PEP8 - spaces after comma and around =
# PEP8 - english names helps when you have to show code 

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

WHITE = (255, 255, 255) 
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED   = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE  = (0, 0, 255)

# Human eye need at least 25 frames per second to see animatioon.
# and it is enough if there is no animation.
# Typical monitors refresh screen with 60 Hz and it means 60 FPS
# so 175 FPS can be useless. 

FPS = 25 

# --- main ---

# - init -

pygame.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Prova")

# - object -

player_rect = pygame.Rect(400, 360, 30, 40)
lead_x_change = 0
lead_y_change = 0

red_rect = pygame.Rect(100, 100, 100, 100)
display_rect = False # to control rect
go_down = False

tracks = []

# - mainloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock() # create only once, before loop
uscita = False

while not uscita:

    # - events -

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            uscita = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                lead_x_change += 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                lead_x_change += -5
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                display_rect = True
                #display_rect = not display_rect
                #tracks.append(player_rect.copy())

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key in (pygame.K_RIGHT, pygame.K_LEFT):
                lead_x_change = 0
            #if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            #    display_rect = False

    # - updates -

    player_rect.x += lead_x_change
    player_rect.y += lead_y_change

    if display_rect:
        if go_down:
           red_rect.y += 5
           if red_rect.bottom > 400:
              red_rect.bottom = 400
        else:
           red_rect.y -= 5
           if red_rect.top <= 0:
              red_rect.top = 0
              go_down = True

    # - draws -

    display.fill((86, 170, 239))

    pygame.draw.rect(display, GREEN, [0, 400, 800, 800])

    if display_rect:
        pygame.draw.rect(display, RED, red_rect)

    for item in tracks:
        pygame.draw.rect(display, BLUE, item)

    pygame.draw.rect(display, RED, player_rect)    

    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(FPS)

# - end -

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

[image]

Comment: it works well, but I didn't need that it copies the player... my mystake, however I have learnt it too. Now how can I make the square falling down? I have tried with a while loop: while y > 20, display_rect = True,  y_change (of the new red square) +=10 and then y_change +=1

Comment: you can't use `while` loop inside `while True`. You have to use `while True` as your `loop` which changes obejcts position in every frame/loop.

Comment: The last problem is that if I want that when it reach y = 0 (the top) it has to fall down it crashe,  the two instructions are conflicting: if it goes down y > 0 so it  raise up

Comment: use variable `go_down = True/False` or `direction = "down"` to control direction.

Comment: you have to use `go_down` similar to `display_rect` . You have to assign `go_down = False` before `while` loop, and use `if go_down: ... else: ...` inside `while` loop. But you do `red_rect.y -= 5` without checking `if go_down:` so it is executed always

Comment: Ok, I added, after `red_rect.bottom = 400`, `display_rect = False` in order to show again the red square when I press the space bar. Why it doesn't do it?

Comment: you have to also set `go_down = False` and change rect positon to start position `red_rect.x = 100` . Briefly you have to reset all values.

Comment: Done, perfect. Why can't I put  a +1, what's the reputation?

Comment: reputation is points which you get for questions, answers, etc. You have reputation 8 points. If you will have more points then you would do more things - ie. you would add images in question, edit other questions, etc. You'll be able to put +1 few minutes/hours after you accept answer.